# Resize SlidesJS Slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have SlidesJS working but for some reason it thinks the frames are bigger than they are. So if I put in 4 paragraphs as slides the slideshow still takes up most of the page.

I tried putting in smaller width and height values in the script at the bottom but it doesn't seemed to have made an difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SlidesJS Standard Code Example</title>
  <meta name="description" content="SlidesJS is a simple slideshow plugin for jQuery. Packed with a useful set of features to help novice and advanced developers alike create elegant and user-friendly slideshows.">
  <meta name="author" content="Nathan Searles">

  <!-- SlidesJS Required (if responsive): Sets the page width to the device width. -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- CSS for slidesjs.com example -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/example.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->
  <!-- The container is used to define the width of the slideshow -->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="slides">
      <p>Hello</p>
      <p>Hello1</p>
      <p>Hello2</p>
      <p>Hello3</p>

      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-previous slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-large"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="slidesjs-next slidesjs-navigation"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-large"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required: Start Slides -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jQuery -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Link to jquery.slides.js -->
  <script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->

  <!-- SlidesJS Required: Initialize SlidesJS with a jQuery doc ready -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 94,
        height: 52
      });
    });
  </script>
  <!-- End SlidesJS Required -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: I figured out that it was the responsive css in example.css that was overriding my height and width.

```
 /* For larger displays */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      .container {
        width: 1170px
      }
```

I changed this width and it finally listened.

I had the same problem. Can't say I really found the right solution but I found a google group talking about this problem. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slidesjs/mvbfqq0Fig4
I basically tried to follow the instructions and put a div around it and set a height and width for that div.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS in example.css is probably overriding the width and height you set in the script. Try adjusting width and height in your CSS.

Comment: I tried removing the CSS altogether and that made the problem worse! I don't know what part of the CSS to edit. I would've thought that on their website they would have said if CSS was needed to edit size of the slideshow.